# Order of environment variables in %PATH%

Tags: environment-variables

```
C:\Python27; C:\Python27\Scripts
```

With this setup, I will have access to Python command in cmd.

```
C:\Python27\Scripts; C:\Python27
```

With this setup, I will have access to easy_install command in cmd.

But I can never have both to work! How do I get around this? I am on win7/8 machine.

Comment: Remove the [space] character.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough! It's always those space that screw me up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to Oswald's Comment. His one liner saved my day.